# C# multi-threading method parameters VS. thread parameters

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the following few lines of code.

mPath is a given path with 3 csv files in it.

What this code does is iterate through all the files in mPath, extract their content, and compare it to a certain data structure that I already have (called "data"), which contains the content of 2 other files. Whatever happens inside of "CopyCompareSingleFile" is irrelevant. I have created a different thread for each file in mPath to be compared with "data".

My problem is, if I transfer filePath as a parameter to my thread, and then from the thread to my method, everything works fine:

```
//Iterate through all files from path #1, and compare with data collected from path #2
LinkedList<Thread> threads = new LinkedList<Thread>();

foreach (string filePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(mPath1, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
{
    var thread = new Thread(file => CopyCompareSingleFile(file.ToString(), data));
    threads.AddLast(thread);
    thread.Start(filePath);
}

//Join all threads
foreach (Thread thread in threads)
{
    thread.Join();
}
```

The output:
[image]

==============================================================

However, My original code was to create these threads *without* transferring parameters to them. Meaning, filePath was transferred as a parameter directly to the method. And the output is weird - It seems like only the last file is being used, for all threads... And I'm not sure why.

Note: If i'll put in "Thread.Sleep(1000)" after the "Start", it will work fine. But I'm wondering why it won't work as it is.

```
//Iterate through all files from path #1, and compare with data collected from path #2
LinkedList<Thread> threads = new LinkedList<Thread>();

foreach (string filePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(mPath1, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
{
    var thread = new Thread(()=> CopyCompareSingleFile(filePath, data));
    threads.AddLast(thread);
    thread.Start();
}

//Join all threads
foreach (Thread thread in threads)
{
    thread.Join();
}
```

The output:
[image]

Comment: What version of VS? See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/

Comment: @SLaks VS2010... you think this is why?

Comment: Yes; see that blog post for a full explanation.

Comment: Just take a local copy of `filePath` within the loop and use that to make your call. The problem will disappear.